# Linq Expression - Extract smallest Integer Array sizes only

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers which will only contain 4 numbers as shown, I need to write a Linq expression which extracts a list of integer Arrays containing only numbers whose addition is equal to "total", sounds simple but here's the tricky part I only want integer Arrays with the smallest count, so if total = 4, then I'd want int[]{4} but I would want int[]{2,2} or int[]{1,3} etc, if total was 5 then I'd want int[]{1,4} , int[]{4,1} , int[]{2,3} , int[]{3,2}, perhaps this could be done with a whole pile of if statements but I'm hoping there's an elegent linq expression out there.

```
var total = 5;
var numList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question... Can you show your attempt? It is an interesting problem though.

Comment: and what have you accomplished so far?

Comment: The only thing I can do so far is extract all integer arrays were four number add up to "total" so if total was 8, then I'd have int[]{2,2,1,3} as one result, but this has four numbers were it could have been done with just int[] {4,4}

Comment: Are you asking for _all possible permutations_ of `numList` that can give you that total? Or are you given an initial set of arrays/permutations to check?

Comment: Yes all permutations of the smallest integer array counts

Comment: And on second read, not only basic permutations but _order permutations_ as well? That is, for the above `numList` for total `7`, both `{3, 4}` _and_ `{4, 3}` would be returned? But not only that: `{1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 1}`?

Comment: @Chris, I'd want only {3, 4} and {4, 3} for total of 7

Comment: @chillydk147: Ahh, my mistake, right, smallest. But if `3` wasn't available, you'd have that many combinations to return?

Comment: @Chris Array will always be {1,2,3,4} and total will never exceed 16

Comment: @chillydk147: Ahh. Well, for the sake of learning/understanding, I'd suggest trying to write it out with a more verbose algorithm and _then_ trying to compose it to LINQ queries. As it stands, you have a couple _different_ tasks here: first you must attempt to find _combinations_ of values that equal your sum ascending in number of picks (that is, start by all possible ways to pick 1, check sums, then if none equal your total, all possible ways to pick 2, and so on), _then_ find all possible order permutations of those picks. _And_ finally, do so for all combination "ties" ({2,2} & {3,1})

Comment: Wow, for input that small, you can hardcode the answers...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Obviously but if there's a linq solution then why not use it

Comment: @chillydk147: cont.: Once you break down your problem to its constituent steps (combinations, summation, & permutations) _and understand how those work_, then you can try rewriting them in more elegant ways or applying LINQ to those individual parts. _Then_ you might be able to write a large LINQ query combining them. Better to get it _working_ first (with automated tests) _then_ try to rewrite them elegantly to make sure your rewritten LINQ queries are _correct_ against your tests.

Comment: @chillydk147 why are you so set on using LINQ for this solution? What benefits do you hope to get from it?

Comment: @Nick: I'm only learning linq since yesterday so just want to play around with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all possible sums that add up to a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331093/getting-all-possible-sums-that-add-up-to-a-given-number)

Answer (score 0):

You have to start out with a fairly complicated bit of code to produce all of the combinations of the source array. Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (!source.Any())
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
    }
    else if (!source.Skip(1).Any())
    {
        return new [] { source, source.Take(0) };
    }
    else
    {
        return Combinations(source.Skip(1))
            .SelectMany(xs => new [] { source.Take(1).Concat(xs), xs });
    }
}
```

Now the rest is easy. Just do this:

```
var query =
(
    from xs in Combinations(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, })
    where xs.Sum() == 5
    orderby xs.Count()
    group xs by xs.Count()
)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(xs => xs);
```

I get the follow result as expected:

[image: result]

Comment: If I make a set, say `Enumerable.Range(1, 1024)`, and I want to find the first combination that sums to `1`, your solution is going to take a very long time to find that.

Comment: @Jodrell - Yes, I agree. It would take around 10^300 seconds to compute. Not very practical. But for small quantities of numbers this works.

Comment: of, course, im my silly test, you could prefilter the list with `numList.Where(n => n <= total)`.

Comment: @Jodrell - Yes, you actually made me think that you could push the filter into the list gen to determine when to stop further processing because either you've gone over the required value or if there are insufficient values in the remaining list to make it viable to continue. The trick would be making sure those checks are efficient - or at least more efficient than blindly moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

okay, here is a function

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets integer combinations between 0 and an exclusive upper bound.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="l">The length of the combination.</param>
/// <param name="n">The exclusive upper bound.</param>
/// <returns>
/// All combinations of the specified length in the specified range.
/// </returns>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Combinations(int l, int n)
{
    var result = new int[l];
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack.Push(0);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var index = stack.Count - 1;
        var value = stack.Pop();

        while (value < n)
        {
            result[index++] = value++;
            stack.Push(value);
            if (index == 1)
            {
                yield return result;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use that in an extension method like this.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CombinationsIncreasingLength<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var sourceList = source.ToList();

    if (sourceList.Count < 2)
    {
        return new[] { sourceList };
    }

    return
        Enumerable.Range(1, sourceList.Count)
            .SelectMany(l => Combinations(l, sourceList.Count)
                .Select(indices => indices.Select(i => sourceList[i])));
}
```

That will give you all the combinations of the `source` **in increasing length**.

So to find the shortest combination that sum exactly to value, you can do.

```
numList.CombinationsIncreasingLength().First(c => c.Sum() == total);
```