# What is the number of ways to choose numbers from 1 to k so that its sum is equal to n?

Tags: algorithm

The problem is as follows: you are given n (1->1000) and k(1->100), find the number of possible ways to pick numbers from
1 to k so that their sum is equal to n.

Here is an example:

```
n = 5; k = 3;
```

Possible ways:

```
1*3 + 1*2 = 5

1*3 + 2*1 = 5

1*2 + 3*1 = 5

2*2 + 1*1 = 5

5*1 = 5
```

==> We get 5 possible ways

I've tried combinations, writing down many examples to find the universal solution but no luck.

Please help me with this, thanks!

Comment: You forgot the question

Comment: @ThomasSablik The title is the question.

Comment: @BirnhBui _"Find number of ways to choose numbers from 1 to k so that its sum is equal to n"_ is not a question. Maybe you both should read [ask]

Comment: You forgot `2*1 + 3*1`

Comment: @JimMischel It should be the first line `1*3 + 1*2` (it's amount * type)

Comment: So `1*2` is "two 1's? And `2*1` is "one 2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you described is known as [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). It requires recurrence to get the solution. I adapted my solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331093/getting-all-possible-sums-that-add-up-to-a-given-number) which contains detailed explanation of the idea. Be careful because this number grows really fast, for instance for n = 100 and k = 6 you'll get 189509 possible sums. Here's the code in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int nrOfSums = 0;
void partition(int n, int max, std::string prefix) {
    if (n == 0) {
        std::cout<<prefix<<std::endl;
        nrOfSums++;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = std::min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
        partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + std::to_string(i));
    }
}
void partition(int n, int k) {
    partition(n, k, "");
}


int main()
{
    int n = 8, k = 3;
    partition(n, k);
    std::cout << "number of possible sums: "<< nrOfSums;
}
```

And the output for n = 8, k = 3:

```
 3 3 2
 3 3 1 1
 3 2 2 1
 3 2 1 1 1
 3 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 1 1
 2 2 1 1 1 1
 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
number of possible sums: 10
```

Comment: Thanks! Never knew partition was a thing haha